# Tsung - Maximum number of concurrent users in a single VM reached

Tags: performance-testing, load-testing, tsung

I am new to tsung performance test. I have installed Tsung in **Mac OS X** using **brew**.
After many tries and resolving few other issues, I am struck with the below error, and I do not find a proper solution elsewhere.

I am facing the below error:

**"Maximum number of concurrent users in a single VM reached and 'use_controller_vm' is true, can't start new beam !!! Check 'maxusers' value in  configuration.~n"**

The command I used to run is:

**tsung -f test_performance.xml start -r ssh_no_check**

where **ssh_no_check** is:

```
#!/bin/sh
/usr/bin/ssh -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $@
```

and test_performance.xml is:

```
<?xml version="2.0"?>   
<!DOCTYPE tsung SYSTEM "/path_to_tsung/tsung-1.0.dtd">
   <tsung loglevel="warning">
  <clients>
      <client host="localhost" use_controller_vm="true" maxusers="100"/>
   </clients>
   <servers>
      <server host="server_ip" port="port_num" type="tcp"/>
   </servers>
   <load>
      <arrivalphase phase="1" duration="60" unit="second">
         <users arrivalrate="300" unit="second"/>
      </arrivalphase>
    </load>
   <sessions>
        <session name="es_load" weight="1" type="ts_http">
        <transaction name="transaction_name">
             <request>

                <http url="url_path" contents="request_body" content_type="application/json" method="POST">
                    <http_header name="header0" value="value0"/>
                    <http_header name="header1" value="value2"/>
                </http>

            </request>
      </transaction>
    </session>
   </sessions>
 </tsung>
```

**NOTE**:
In the above config xml, I have changed the server's host, port, http url, and headers values for safety & privacy.

Please help me in resolving this problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your xml needs a bit of change:

In your client tag, you have mentioned the `maxusers` as 100.

But in `users arrival rate` you have configured as 300.
Change it to 10, it will work for you.

Extra point, if you want to generate report, just run the
 `tsung_stats.pl` command in the folder where the logs gets created, it will provide you a beautiful html report :)

Comment: thanks, it worked smooth... thanks a lot for your help.. I was desperate for the solution!!!